# How to expire other users session in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm newbie of Spring Security and I have problem with expire user session.
In my application, there are administrator with `ROLE_ADMIN` and they can change other users role.

I want to expire the session of user whose authority is changed by administrator.
I found that I can get all logged-in users session by using SessionRegistry.

I checked that I can get all SessionInformation with `sessionRegistry.getAllSessions()` and I tried to expire session information with below codes.

```java
List<SessionInformation> sessionInformations = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(allPrincipals.get(i), false);

for (SessionInformation information : sessionInformations) {
    information.expireNow();
    sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(information.getSessionId());
}

allPrincipals.set(i, new AccountUserAdaptor(requestedAccount));
```

I thought above code is enough to expire session of specific other user.
But in `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` authentication is recovered from session which I thought it already expired.

I checked that with `request.getSession()` I can get valid session which I thought was already expired. Even SessionID in `information.getSessionId()` and `request.getSession()` is same.

I want to know why session is not expired.

**I'm using Spring(not Spring-Boot)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **spring-session** with **jdbc or redis**, You can use this code to clear session of any user. Autowire this dependency

```
@Autowired
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessionRepo;
```

Pass the email/username of the user you want to clear the session.

```
Set<String> sessionIds = sessionRepo
                .findByIndexNameAndIndexValue(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME, userEmail)
                .keySet();

if (sessionIds.size() > 0) {
    log.debug("existing sessions: {}", sessionIds.size());
    for (String sessionId : sessionIds) {
        sessionRepo.deleteById(sessionId);
    }
}
```